# Problem regarding borrowing references in Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a program in which one thread writes to a queue and another thread
reads from the queue

But I am facing an issue regarding accessing the 'queue' in the thread that reads the queue

Below is the code which is not compiling

```
use ::std::collections::VecDeque;
use notify::{Config, RecommendedWatcher, RecursiveMode, Watcher};
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    //let path = std::env::args()
    //   .nth(1)
    //   .expect("Argument 1 needs to be a path");
    //println!("watching {}", path);
    let path = "c:\\testfolder";

    if let Err(e) = watch(path) {
        println!("error: {:?}", e)
    }
}

fn process_queue(queue: &VecDeque<String>) -> () {}

fn watch<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> notify::Result<()> {
    let (tx, rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();
    // Automatically select the best implementation for your platform.
    // You can also access each implementation directly e.g. INotifyWatcher.
    let mut watcher = RecommendedWatcher::new(tx, Config::default())?;

    // Add a path to be watched. All files and directories at that path and
    // below will be monitored for changes.
    let mut queue: VecDeque<String> = VecDeque::new();

    thread::spawn(|| {
        // everything in here runs
        process_queue(&queue)
    });

    watcher.watch(path.as_ref(), RecursiveMode::Recursive)?;

    for res in rx {
        match res {
            Ok(event) => {
                println!("changed: {:?}", event.paths);
                let os_str: String = String::from(event.paths[0].to_str().unwrap());
                //let my_str: String = os_str.unwrap().to_str().unwrap();
                //let s =os_str.into_os_string();

                queue.push_back(os_str);
            }
            Err(e) => println!("watch error: {:?}", e),
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

The output from the Rust compiler

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `queue`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src\main.rs:43:19
   |
43 |     thread::spawn(|| {
   |                   ^^ may outlive borrowed value `queue`
...
47 |         process_queue(&queue)
   |                        ----- `queue` is borrowed here
   |
note: function requires argument type to outlive `'static`
  --> src\main.rs:43:5
   |
43 | /     thread::spawn(|| {
44 | |
45 | |         // everything in here runs
46 | |
47 | |         process_queue(&queue)
48 | |
49 | |     });
   | |______^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `queue` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
43 |     thread::spawn(move || {
   |                   ++++

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `queue` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src\main.rs:63:17
   |
43 |       thread::spawn(|| {
   |       -             -- immutable borrow occurs here
   |  _____|
   | |
44 | |
45 | |         // everything in here runs
46 | |
47 | |         process_queue(&queue)
   | |                        ----- first borrow occurs due to use of `queue` in closure
48 | |
49 | |     });
   | |______- argument requires that `queue` is borrowed for `'static`
...
63 |                   queue.push_back(os_str);
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

From the errors I understand that the compiler does not allow both mutable and immutable references at the same time.

But I don't know how to implement what I am trying to do with these restrictions.

Comment: You probably want to use a channel instead of a VecDeque.

Comment: Did you read the [Fearless Concurrency](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-00-concurrency.html) chapter of The Book yet?  It covers pretty much this exact thing, and why you can't take references between threads this way.

Comment: Why do you need to share the queue between the main thread and the other thread you started? Couldn't you write `process_queue(rx)`, and move the `for` loop to the thread? As far as I can tell, that would resolve all your issues.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is by `Box`-ing the `VecDeque` so that you can pass a cloned reference to your `process_queue` function.

Using a [Box](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html) allows you to allocate the `VecDeque` on the heap so that you can give your spawned thread a reference to the Vec and also still mutate the queue in the current thread.

This would look like:

```rust
let mut queue = Box::new(VecDeque::new());
let queue_clone = queue.clone();

thread::spawn(|| {
    // queue_clone is now moved into the fn closure and is 
    // not accessible to the code below
    process_queue(queue_clone)
});
```

and you can update `process_queue` to accept the correct type:

```rust
fn process_queue(queue: Box<VecDeque<String>>) -> () { }
```

Note that with this implementation, `process_queue` only runs once when the thread is spawned, and if you want to have process_queue do something every time the queue is changed, following the advice of others to use something like [Channels](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std_misc/channels.html) makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your responses

From all the responses I understand that using channels and moving the receiver loop to the other  thread  as suggested bu user4815162342
will be the best solution

Answer (score 0):

I successfully implemented what I was trying to do using channels based on your suggestions.

The final working code is pasted below

```
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use notify::{RecommendedWatcher, RecursiveMode, Watcher, Config};
use std::path::Path;
use std::path::PathBuf;


//
fn main() {
   
    
    //let path = std::env::args()
     //   .nth(1)
     //   .expect("Argument 1 needs to be a path");
    //println!("watching {}", path);
    let path="c:\\testfolder";    

    if let Err(e) = watch(path) {
        println!("error: {:?}", e)
    }
    
}





fn watch<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> notify::Result<()> {
    let (tx, rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();      
    
    // Automatically select the best implementation for your platform.
    // You can also access each implementation directly e.g. INotifyWatcher.
    let mut watcher = RecommendedWatcher::new(tx, Config::default())?;

    // Add a path to be watched. All files and directories at that path and
    // below will be monitored for changes.
    
    let handle=thread::spawn(move || {

        // everything in here runs        
        
        for res in rx {
            match res {
                Ok(event) =>{
                
                   // println!("changed: {:?}", event.paths); 
                    let os_str:String = String::from(event.paths[0].to_str().unwrap());
                    println!("file name: {}", os_str);               
                    
                },
                Err(e) => println!("watch error: {:?}", e),
            }
        }
        
    }); 

    watcher.watch(path.as_ref(), RecursiveMode::Recursive)?;    
    handle.join();  

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your situation, using Rust's MPSC (multi-producer single-consumer, ie essentially a queue) would probably be the best. You could also create a variable that is shared between multiple thread using `Arc` and `Mutex` structs, but that would be way overkilled and can have a performance impact (only one can access the variable at any time).

Here is an example of a multi-threaded MPSC, I will let you adapt it to your infrastructure :

```rust
use std::{sync::mpsc, thread};

fn main() {
    let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel();
    
    let handle_1 = thread::spawn(|| {
        thread_1(sender);
    });
    let handle_2 = thread::spawn(|| {
        thread_2(receiver);
    });

    handle_1.join().unwrap();
    handle_2.join().unwrap();
}

// the enum must have the Send trait (automatically implemented)
enum Instruction {
    Print(String),
    Exit
}

fn thread_1(sender: mpsc::Sender<Instruction>) {
    sender.send(Instruction::Print("I".to_owned())).unwrap();
    sender.send(Instruction::Print("like".to_owned())).unwrap();
    sender.send(Instruction::Print("Rust".to_owned())).unwrap();
    sender.send(Instruction::Print(".".to_owned())).unwrap();
    sender.send(Instruction::Exit).unwrap();
}

fn thread_2(receiver: mpsc::Receiver<Instruction>) {
    'global_loop: loop {
        for received in receiver.recv() {
            match received {
                Instruction::Print(string) => print!("{} ", string),
                Instruction::Exit => {
                    println!("");
                    break 'global_loop;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response
Since I am extremely new to 'Rust', the code you have provided is a bit confusing
I tried using the Arc and Mutex structs but could not get them to work

If possible please give me an example using  Arc and Mutex structs

Comment: There are a ton of SO answers that show how to use channels. If you don't show how OP should apply it to _their_ problem, it would be better to just make this question a duplicate and link to one of the existing explanations.

Comment: @mjk6035 Channels are the more appropriate solution for this problem - and easier to use too.

Comment: @PeterHall  thanks for your response
The problem is that I am implementing a Directory Watcher application which already contains a Channel. I f I try to add one more channel I get an error

Comment: An error because you are using the same variable names? Use different names.

Comment: I added the line 'let (sender, receiver) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();' 
to my code

I get the error below

let (sender, receiver) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type of the type parameter `T` declared on the function 
`channel`

Comment: I implemented the channel successfully but it looks like  my requirement of sharing the queue itself with another thread using channels wont be possible